# Is it possible to hide a menu item using menu blocks in context based on user roles?

Tags: 7, blocks

I am using the Menu block module to create menu blocks and have them attached to the menu in Drupal 7.  I am also using the Context module to display the menu and items on different pages.

I have a certain menu item that I want only to be visible with certain user roles.  I have created a context for the page (based on "path") that linked to the menu item and have selected the administrator role as a condition and selected require both (path and user role).

Using a non-admin test user I can still see the menu item (It should be hidden).  When I click on it the page content doesn't show but the menu item is still visible to the user.

How do I use Context to hide the menu item as well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you could hide it programatically

```
function YOURTEMPLATE_menu_alter(&$items) {

 global $user;

  if (in_array('anonymous user', $user->roles)) {
  unset($items['user/%user/profile']);   // example link
  }

 }
```

This will hide that menu item for anonymous users.